# Subprocess.run() does not wait for completion upon execution through cron

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I'm aware that `subprocess.run()` waits for the process to end. It is working as expected when the py script is executed manually. However my issue is when the same file is executed through cron, the script won't wait till the subprocess command to finish. Is there anything which I should be considering for any sort of automated execution.

My Code :

pysample.py

```
import subprocess

print("Executing py script")

for i in range(10):
  print(i)

print("Invoking shell script")
subprocess.run(['/etc/sensu/plugins/sample.sh'])

print("Back to py")

for i in range(5):
  print(i)
```

sample.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "executing shell script"
sleep 10s
echo -e "completed execution"
```

cron

```
*/5 * * * * python3.6 pysample.py > output.txt
```

Comment: can you try it with **subprocess.run(['/etc/sensu/plugins/sample.sh']) == 0**, this may make it wait for the return

Comment: How do you determine whether your python script waited for the shell script?

Comment: @iBug, Through print and eco statements I'm determining the order..